# TextView does not update TableView

Tags: ios

I was being helped by another person on StackOverflow, They showed me an example to allow me to place text in a `UITextView` which then automatically shows in a `UITableView`. It works fine on his side, however for some reason on my side nothing happens.

Heres the code.

.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UITextViewDelegate>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *txtView;
```

.m

```
@interface ViewController ()<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UITextViewDelegate> {

NSMutableArray *listArray;
 }

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}


cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];;

return cell;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

return listArray.count;
}

-(void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{

listArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[textView.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]]];
[self.tableView reloadData];

NSLog(@"Array-- %@",listArray);

NSLog(@"Array Count-- %lu",(unsigned long)listArray.count);

NSLog(@"Text-- %@",textView.text);

}
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Are all the delegates and datasource for the tableview and textview setup correctly in the xib/storyboard?

Comment: What Delegate do i need to connect?

Comment: go to XIB, connect tableview with delegates and datasources. You can also add the breakpoint to check whether tableview methods are working or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your problem is your delegates setup. You can do it programmatically in your `viewDidLoad` like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.txtView.delegate = self;
}
```

Comment: Thank you worked perfectly ill make sure i click the tick button, it just says i have to wait another 30seconds